# Selecting an entire colum to show values in a Textbox

Tags: c#

i am having a data grid view with different columns been loaded from a sql database and i would like to select an entire column and display each selected cell value in a particular textbox so that i can compare the values and save each cell values to their respective cells. the data grid below shows the data grid i would like to select all the values in column Value and show all its values of each cell in my textbox:

```
                                     Value
Realization   Occurrence   EventID              
1             207          2023378    20
              213          2012388    25
              291          2012612    28
              324          2036783    12
              357          2255910    45
              399          2166643    64
              420          2022922    19
2             207          2010673    56
              249          2018319    77
              282          2166809    43
```

can anyone answer my question accurately however i am using wpf
i wan to compare each values to know the highest and lowest grade each and save each back to each respective data grid cells

Comment: Please don't SHOUT when posting. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and won't get you help any faster.

Comment: In addition, you need to actually show what you've tried so far.  This is simply a request for a solution, not a demonstration of your effort to date.

Comment: Just data not enough, show how you populate your DataGrid, what data structures you are using.